# Unit testing void method that creates a new object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, rhino-mocks

I have a method like the following:

```
public void ExecuteSomeCommand()
{
    new MyCommand( someInt, SomeEnum.EnumValue ).Execute();
}
```

I'd like to test that the enum value that is passed in to the constructor of the ICommand object I'm creating is the correct value. Is there any way I can do this with Rhino.Mocks?

Comment: Does the constructor throw an exception if the enum value is unexpected?

Comment: The constructor itself doesn't throw. The arguments are passed by the Execute method to the view model of a view that is created via a NavigationManager class. The new view model then uses the enum for some display property and if it is an unexpected value, it throws.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Option 1: Use a Seam***

**The easiest way** is to refactor that method with a seam:

```
public void ExecuteSomeCommand()
{
    this.CreateCommand(someInt, SomeEnum.EnumValue).Execute();
}

// Your seam
protected virtual ICommand CreateCommand(int someInt, 
    SomeEnum someEnum)
{
    return new MyCommand(someInt, SomeEnum.EnumValue);
}
```

This way you can intercept the creation of the 'new' operator by extending this class. When doing this by hand, it might look like this:

```
public FakeSomeService : SomeService
{
    public int SomeInt;
    public SomeEnum SomeEnum;

    protected override Command CreateCommand(int someInt, 
        SomeEnum someEnum)
    {
        this.SomeInt = someInt;
        this.SomeEnum = someEnum;
        return new FakeCommand();
    }

    private sealed class FakeCommand : Command
    {
        public override void Execute() { }
    }
}
```

This fake class can be used in your test methods.

---

***Option 2: Separate behavior and data***

**A better way** would be to separate the data from the behavior. You command has both data (the message) and the behavior (handling that message). If you are allowed to do such a change in your code base: separate this, for instance by defining commands and command handlers. Here is an example:

```
// Define an interface for handling commands
public interface IHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

// Define your specific command
public class MyCommand
{
    public int SomeInt;
    public SomeEnum SomeEnum;
}

// Define your handler for that command
public class MyCommandHandler : IHandler<MyCommand>
{
    public void Handle(MyCommand command)
    {
        // here your old execute logic
    }
}
```

Now you can use **dependency injection** to inject a handler into the class you wish to test. This class will now look like this:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IHandler<MyCommand> handler;

    // Inject a handler here using constructor injection.
    public SomeService(IHandler<MyCommand> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void ExecuteSomeCommand()
    {
        this.handler.Handle(new MyCommand
        {
            SomeInt = someInt,
            SomeEnum = someEnum
        });
    }
}
```

Since you now separated the data from the behavior, it will be very easy to create a fake command handler (or create it using Rhino mocks) that checks if the correct command was sent to the handler. Manually this would look like this:

```
public class FakeHandler<TCommand> : IHandler<TCommand>
{
    public TCommand HandledCommand { get; set; }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        this.HandledCommand = command;
    }
}
```

This fake handler can be reused throughout your unit testing project. A test using this `FakeHandler` could look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    // Arrange
    int expected = 23;

    var handler = new FakeHandler<MyCommand>();

    var service = new SomeService(handler);

    // Act
    service.ExecuteSomeCommand();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, handler.HandledCommand.SomeInt);
}
```

Separating the data from the behavior not only makes your application more testable. It makes your application more resilient to change. For instance, cross-cutting concerns can be added to the execution of commands, without the need to make changes to any handler in the system. Because the `IHandler<T>` is an interface with a single method, it is very easy to write a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that can wrap every handler and add things like logging, audit trailing, profiling, validation, transaction handling, fault tolerance improvents, etc. You can read more about it in [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Comment: I went with your first suggestion. The fake class wasn't necessary though. I was able to use Rhino.Mocks' AssertWasCalled(...) to check the correct parameters were passed into the CreateCommand(...) method. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Alimbada: Thanks. But don't forget about handlers. Think about how this can simplify your tests and your design.

Answer (score 2):

None that I'm aware of. The closest thing that comes to my mind is to use a factory, then create a `StrictMock` of that factory. Something like that:

```
readonly ICommandFactory factory;

public Constructor(ICommandFactory factory)
{
    this.factory = factory;
}
public void ExecuteSomeCommand()
{
    factory.Create( someInt, SomeEnum.EnumValue ).Execute();
}
```

then, you can place expectations on invokation to `Create()`.

HTH

Comment: You will probably need a command factory per specific command if you do this. In the case of the OP that class needs a `IMyCommandFactory`. This would probably be less ideal. Still +1 for using (constructor) dependency injection.